# Rotating a line in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I want to make a line rotate. I studied the pi and radians and I made my own algorithm (if I can call it like that). I don't like to use already-made code from the Internet. I want to discover them alone, but using logic. Here is the code:

```
Dim pi As Double
Dim a, b, c, d, e, x, y As Double
Dim speed, radius As Integer

   Private Sub Form_Load()
       pi = 3.14159265358979
       speed = 1
       radius = 600
   End Sub

   Private Sub Command1_Click()

       Timer1.Enabled = Not Timer1.Enabled
       If Timer1.Enabled = True Then
           Command1.Caption = "Stop"
       Else
           Command1.Caption = "Start"
       End If
   End Sub


   Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

       ForeColor = vbWhite
       timer1.interval=speed
       Refresh

       a = a + 2
       b = Sin((a * pi) / 180)
       c = Cos((a * pi) / 180)
       y = radius * b
       x = radius * c

       Call Label1.Move(6240 + x, 4200 + y)
       If Left(b, 1) = "-" Then
           Label1.Caption = "---"
       Else
           Label1.Caption = "+++"
       End If

       If Left(c, 1) = "-" Then
           Label1.Caption = Label1.Caption & " " & "---"
       Else
           Label1.Caption = Label1.Caption & " " & "+++"
       End If

       Line (3000 + x, 4200 + y)-(6240 + x, 4200 + y)
       Line (3000, 4200)-(3000 + x, 4200 + y)
       Line (6240, 4200)-(6240 + x, 4200 + y)

       For d = 3000 To 6240
           Line (d, 4200)-(3000 + x, 4200 + y)
       Next

       For e = 3000 + x To 6240 + x
           Line (e, 4200 + y)-(6240, 4200)
       Next

   End Sub
```

I want to rotate the line on x-axis, not z (it appears to be z). I recalculated everything, but I don't see where is the problem. What would be an explained formula?

Comment: have you stepped it one line at a time in the debugger and watched what happens?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are after the following effect:

```
Option Explicit

Dim D As Long, S As Long, Y As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Timer1.Enabled = Not Timer1.Enabled
    If Timer1.Enabled = True Then
        Command1.Caption = "Stop"
    Else
        Command1.Caption = "Start"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    D = 1 'Start going down; change to 0 to start going up instead
    Y = 100 'Mid point

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

    If S Then
        If S = 8 Then
            S = 0
        Else
            S = S + 1
            lblRate = "0"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    Refresh
    If D Then
        If Y < 200 Then
            Select Case Y
            Case Is < 20
                'Begin to accelerate
                Y = Y + 1
                lblRate = "+1"
            Case Is < 40
                'Continue to accelerate
                Y = Y + 2
                lblRate = "+2"
            Case Is < 160
                'Set acceleration to peak
                Y = Y + 3
                lblRate = "+3"
            Case Is < 180
                'Begin to decelerate
                Y = Y + 2
                lblRate = "+2"
            Case Else
                'Continue to decelerate
                Y = Y + 1
                lblRate = "+1"
            End Select
        Else
            'Stop and reverse direction
            D = 0
            S = 1
            lblRate = "0"
        End If
    Else
        If Y > 0 Then
            Select Case Y
            Case Is < 20
                'Begin to accelerate
                Y = Y - 1
                lblRate = "-1"
            Case Is < 40
                'Continue to accelerate
                Y = Y - 2
                lblRate = "-2"
            Case Is < 160
                'Set acceleration to peak
                Y = Y - 3
                lblRate = "-3"
            Case Is < 180
                'Begin to decelerate
                Y = Y - 2
                lblRate = "-2"
            Case Else
                'Continue to decelerate
                Y = Y - 1
                lblRate = "-1"
            End Select
        Else
            'Stop and reverse direction
            D = 1
            S = 1
        End If
    End If
    Line (120, 100)-(120, Y)

End Sub
```

While not technically following a properly calculated curvature, it is more of a simplified version of a line rotating around the X-axis.

Also, make sure to use the Pixel scale mode, rather than Twips, for better drawing performance.